# system("cp /1.txt /2.txt", $out); just doesn't work?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to work with php system (exec) functions to run some commands on linux, but it just doesn't work!

I've logged into the system with root user. I created "/1.txt" file and then I ran this php script through apache server: `system("sudo cp /1.txt /2.txt", $out);` but it doesn't copy the file.

Can you explain why it doesn't work? (I'm new to linux os please explain)

Comment: You're not giving the password for `sudo`, maybe?

Comment: How should i give password for sudo?

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `sudo` and give permissions to apache's user on /1.txt and /2.txt, it should work.

If /2.txt doesn't exist, create a directory, put 1.txt on that directory and give permissions to apache user both on the directory and on the file.

Answer (score 0):

/1.txt and /2.txt are at the very top level of the filesystem - is that what you're aiming to do? Either way it's not a good idea.

I'd recommend having an area which your files are in, for example /var/webapp-files/ that way you can do something like:

```
define('WEBAPP_FILES_LOCATION', '/var/webapp-files');
system("cp ".WEBAPP_FILES_LOCATION."/1.txt ".WEBAPP_FILES_LOCATION."/2.txt", $out);
```

NOTE: I've defined a constant for the location because it'll be needed in a number of different places and you don't wanna start repeating yourself in case you want to change it any time.

What this'll do is run the system command:

```
cp /var/webapp-files/1.txt /var/webapp-files/2.txt
```

Which should succeed **if** your /var/webapp-files directory has write access for your apache user.

**However...** PHP does have a built-in function for copying which I'd recommend using instead of the more generic and dangerous system().  You can read about copy() at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php This will need the full paths as cp does so you can refactor my previous example to:

```
define('WEBAPP_FILES_LOCATION', '/var/webapp-files');
$copySucceeded = copy(WEBAPP_FILES_LOCATION."/1.txt", WEBAPP_FILES_LOCATION."/2.txt");
echo "The copy attempt ". ($copySucceeded ? "succeeded" : "failed");
```

Hope that helps.